# glmm unbalanced nested random factors

Tags: r, glmm, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

imagine you have the following data structure

```
                                     data
                                       |
                                       |
                   env1    env2    env3    env4      env5
                    |       |       |        |         |
    replicates   1,2,3    4,5,6    7,8       9         10
```

At each replicate you apply your nominal treatment A & B and measure your response for each replicate at under seqeuntial A and B treatments. So each replicate has a data point for A and B treatments.

Using `lme4` a GLMM of this data might look like:

```
glmer(response ~ treatment + (1|env/replicate), family=poisson, data=data)
```

I would like to know what are the effects (repercussions for my model) of having only one replicate per environment in some of the cases?

Comment: *"I would like to know what are the effects (repercussions for my model) of having only one replicate per environment in some of the cases"* - the question is not clear - effect on WHAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** I *think* a Poisson GLMM should work fine with this setup and only one replicate for some `env` levels.  Some of the individual latent variables will be confounded with each other, but the random-effect variance estimates should be OK (??). (Sorry, don't know if this counts as "answer drawing from credible and/or official sources" ...)

The relevant statistical model for the response of the $i$th replicate from the $j$th environment is

$$
Y_{ij} \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu_{ij}) \\
\mu_i \sim ({\mathbf X} \beta)_{ij} + \epsilon_i + \epsilon_j \\
\epsilon_i \sim \text{Normal}(0,\sigma^2_{\text{rep}}) \\
\epsilon_j \sim \text{Normal}(0,\sigma^2_{\text{env}}) \\
$$

(I could have written this out as ${\mathbf X} \beta + {\mathbf Z}b$, but for this simple case it's easier to write out the random effects explicitly.) Since there is a unique value of $ij$ for each observation, the replicate-level random effect corresponds to modeling overdispersion (i.e. a logNormal-Poisson model).

As discussed above, $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ will be confounded/perfectly correlated/jointly unidentifiable for any $j$ where there is only one replicate, but I don't think this will interfere with the fitting of the model. Since this is a technical/algorithmic point, I don't know of a way of checking other than by simulation.

If there were too large a proportion of cases with a very small number of replicates, that could make it practically difficult to jointly estimate $\sigma^2_{\text{rep}}$ and $\sigma^2_{\text{env}}$.

Here's a single simulation example (requires the development version of `lme4`) that says that at least in one reasonably best-case scenario, we can recover reasonable parameter estimates:

```
library(lme4)
packageVersion("lme4")  ## 1.1.2
set.seed(101)
nlevs <- 20
nreps <- rpois(nlevs,lambda=3)+1
sum(nreps==1)  ## this gives 2 cases with only 1 rep per treatment
d <- data.frame(env=factor(rep(seq(nlevs),nreps)),
               rep=factor(unlist(sapply(nreps,seq))))
d$trt <- factor(sample(c("control","trt"),size=nrow(d),replace=TRUE))
    d$y <- simulate(~trt+(1|env/rep),family=poisson,
        newdata=d,
        newparam=list(beta=c(1,3),theta=c(1,1)))[[1]]
(g1 <- glmer(y~trt+(1|env/rep),family=poisson,data=d))
## Random effects:
##  Groups  Name        Std.Dev.
##  rep:env (Intercept) 1.101   
##  env     (Intercept) 1.137   
## Number of obs: 79, groups: rep:env, 79; env, 20
## Fixed Effects:
## (Intercept)       trttrt  
##       1.137        2.690
```

The Wald confidence intervals on the treatment effect do include the true value (3) in this case ...

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker this covers the ground I was hoping, I might have a go at the simulation route as well. Thanks!